# How to get a Reference on a list of a class?

Tags: c++

I am very new to c++ and run into a problem.

S this was given inside the .h in class myClass:

`std::vector<uint64_t> getList() const;`

Now i did this in the MyClass (.h File):

`private: std::vector<uint64_t> list;`

And this in my .cpp File:

```
std::vector<uint64_t> MyClass::getList() const{
    return list;
}
```

But now if I want to push a value on the list, I only get a copy of the list and pushing on it.

```
auto list = getList();
list.push_back(1);
```

Someone gave me a hint with references and tryed this:

```
auto& listRef = getList();
listRef.push_back(1);
```

I really don't know how to get it to work... I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. It is not possible to insert something into the member vector using only the `getList` method, if you cannot modify it, then you need to use something else

Answer (score 1):

Return the list by reference by modifying the signature this way:

```
std::vector<uint64_t>& MyClass::getList();
```

In both .hpp and .cpp file

If you cannot change the existing signature, you could implement a new method called differently like that
In header:

```
std::vector<uint64_t>& accessList();
```

In cpp

```
std::vector<uint64_t>& MyClass::accessList()
{
     return list;
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to change the MyClass::getList() in the .h as it is given (It will be accessed from outside for tests).

And even if I try try I only get another error Message: 
qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type "std::vector<uint64_t, std::allocator<uint64_t>> &" to initializer of type "const std::vector<uint64_t, std::allocator<uint64_t>>"

Comment: That works in terms that there are no errors, but the test still uses getList() which results in a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" while trying to access  >.<.